# onChange react event calls function with parameters but no arguments passed?

Tags: reactjs, components, jsx

I'm not really clear on what to title this question.  My question is a more basic understanding level then an actual problem.  I'm new to react.  I don't understand this component function below on the line:

```
<input type='text' name='myinput' value={this.state.input} onChange = {this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
```

this handleChange function that is called has an event parameter but what is the event?  Is event more of just a react key word then an actual argument passed?  I do not understand?

Full component:

```js
class ControlledInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: ""
    };
    // change code below this line
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    // change code above this line
  }
  // change code below this line
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      input: event.target.value
    });
  }
  // change code above this line
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* change code below this line */}
        <input
          type="text"
          name="myinput"
          value={this.state.input}
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
        />
        {/* change code above this line */}
        <h4>Controlled Input:</h4>
        <p>{this.state.input}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I guess if anyone out there can break down how this works for me?  Logically I do not get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event you're receiving in the `onChange` function is just the native event sent by the browser when te change happens.

It is basically an object that holds some information about the *thing* that just happened. In this case the `target` property holds the the `<input />` element. So accessing `event.target.value` will give you the value of the input element.

Furthermore it holds other data/functions that you can use to manipulate how the browser handles what happens. For example, you could use `preventDefault()` to block the default behaviour that might occur when the event is dispatched. Like when you're submitting a form you might want to stop the default behaviour from happening to handle the submit logic yourself.

You can read more about the `Event` interface here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

And about specifically the change event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

---

Also, in the constructor you're already binding `this` to the function, so you don't have to do it again. `onChange={this.handleChange}` should work just fine.